# How to plot survival relative to general population with age on the X-axis (left-truncated data)?

Tags: plot, survival-analysis

I am trying to compare the survival in my study cohort with the survival in the Dutch general population (matched for age and sex). I created a rate table of the Dutch population.

```
library(relsurv)
setwd("")
nldpop <- transrate.hmd("mltper_1x1.txt","fltper_1x1.txt")
```

Then, I wanted to create a plot of the survival of my cohort (observed) and the survival of the population (expected) with age on the X-axis. However, the 'survexp' function does not seem to support a (start,stop,event)-format. Only with the normal (futime, event)-format it works, see below, but then I have follow-up time on the X-axis. Does anyone know how to get the age on the X-axis instead of follow-up time?

```
# Observed and expected survival with time on X-axis
fit <- survfit(Surv(futime, event)~1)
efit <- survexp(futime ~ 1, rmap = list(year=(date_entry), age=(age_entry), sex=(sex)),
          ratetable=nldpop)
plot(fit)
lines(efit)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide your example data, so i used survival::mgus data for this. Your problem may be due to incorrectly specifying variable names in the rmap option. [See plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rb6sb.png)

```html
library(relsurv)
nldpop <- transrate.hmd("mltper_1x1.txt", "fltper_1x1.txt")

mgus2 <- mgus %>% mutate(date_year = dxyr + 1900)

fit <- survfit(Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data = mgus2)
efit <- survexp(Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data = mgus2, 
                ratetable = nldpop, rmap = list(age = age*365.25, year = date_year, sex = sex))
plot(fit)
lines(efit)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The plot you provided is similar to the one I got from my data (follow-up time on X-axis). My question remains whether there is any way to show the survival on an age-scale instead of time-scale.